# 2 VS2010 solutions, 2 similar .pro files. One solution is unable to access any of the headers in the INCLUDEPATH

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, qmake, qt-vs-addin

I have two Qt .pro files which are being used to compile to visual studio 2010 solutions. One compiles to a qt library/dll, and the other is an application.

The library .pro file:

http://ideone.com/3gll0

The application .pro file:

http://ideone.com/gdruV

In the library's solution, I cannot do the following, anywhere:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

Or
    #include "NuiApi.h"

However, it works if I do so in the main.cpp or qpowerpointmod.cpp files of the main application.

So yeah... Also, my apologies for the appalling code in the .pro files, I've been struggling with this for hours today.